# Taking input from one text file and searching on another

Tags: python, python-2.7

Part of my script pings PC's and if they're off, writes their name to a txt file. What I then need to do is search for that PC name in another txt file (an export from our DHCP server) and find it's mac address, which I can then use to do other things. It's this searching part that's causing me problems - it's probably just a syntax issue, but I can't get it to go through the first txt file and for every entry in it, search the second txt file and get the info I need.

Here's what I have so far:

```
            with open (r"PCs_off.txt") as file:
            lines = []
            for line in file:
                line = line.strip()
                pcName = line
                with open("dhcp-dump.txt", "r") as search:
                    for lines in search:
                        if pcName in lines:
                            lines_split = lines.rstrip("\n").split('\t')
                            mac = lines_split[4]
                            print mac
                            print pcName
```

(Forgive the tabbing, it's just this part of the script is in the middle of the bigger script.)
I think the problem lies in the `if pcName in lines:` line - If I specify a PC's name in there, it'll search and work perfectly, but I need it to search on the PC name from the above file.

I hope all this makes sense...

On a slightly different note; the `for line in file` lines, does it actually have to be called 'line' or can I call it anything else? I only ask because calling it 'lines' seems to work too...

Comment: You can call a variable `didgeridoo` if you want so long as you're consistent. The only issue is that if you accidentally over-write a previously used variable, for instance you use both `line` and `lines` in your code separately.

Comment: Advice: don't use reserved keywords as variable names (file - reserved) :)

Comment: @Ffisegydd: Thanks - that's good to know. I used both line and lines because it's effectively doing two searches and I wanted to try and keep them distinct. That may well be half of my problem...!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the exact same sample as yours and it worked perfectly. Can you please try to debug a bit the `pcName` variable? Add `print '<', pcName, '>'` under line `pcName = line`: I wonder if what you got as `pcName` is exactly what you expect...

Comment: Thanks for the reply Emmanuel!
Adding the extra print line does print out the correct info. But it doesn't use it to then search the other file..

Comment: So, if you remove the outer loop, then do `pcName = <a correct PC name>` and just do the inner loop, do you confirm you've got a correct result ?

Comment: yes it works then. I'm thinking I need to translate the variable, pcName, into a string or something? I tried "pcName = str(pcName)" but that didn't help..